# Setting regional culture with LUIS

Tags: botframework, azure-language-understanding

Passing a date to LUIS in the format "3/1/2017" returns a builtin.datetimev2 entity resolved to 1 March 2013.

Month first is a US convention for date strings, but not in my locale where this string generally represents 1 Jan 2017.

Here is the JSON response:

```
    {
  "entity": "23/12/17",
  "type": "builtin.datetimeV2.date",
  "startIndex": 70,
  "endIndex": 77,
  "resolution": {
    "values": [
      {
        "timex": "2017-12-23",
        "type": "date",
        "value": "2017-12-23"
      }
    ]
  }
},
{
  "entity": "3/1/18",
  "type": "builtin.datetimeV2.date",
  "startIndex": 83,
  "endIndex": 88,
  "resolution": {
    "values": [
      {
        "timex": "2018-03-01",
        "type": "date",
        "value": "2018-03-01"
      }
    ]
  }
},
```

Comment: What is your LUIS project language value? `en-us`?

Comment: @NicolasR Yes. It is. I don't seem able to edit that value. The only thing I can change is the application name.

Comment: And there's only one English option when creating a new application, which I assume is en-us

Comment: I quickly checked, yes it is `en-us`. Maybe you can try with LUIS API to change the settings, but I would be surprised if it is working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

builtin.datetimeV2.date is currently always en-us, and there isn't a way to change it.

There's a UserVoice request you can vote on here: https://cognitive.uservoice.com/forums/551524-luis/suggestions/31549864-luis-add-support-for-english-regional-formats

Sorry this isn't the answer you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks. Voted for the UV request

Comment: I guess knowing that the response is en-US the best option is passing in my local CultureInfo when calling DateTime.Parse  on the entity value.

Comment: Yes, currently it is on the developer to ensure the date is culture specific.